# IN statment in JPQL with GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa, jpql

I try to use JPA with GAE, and i have next problem:

when I perform this query:

```
select x From Advert x where x.advertType in (15)
```

or

```
select x From Advert x where x.advertType in (20)
```

Entity manager returns one entity in both cases
but when i try to execute

```
select x From Advert x where x.advertType in (15,20)
```

reurns zero entity

This my mapping:

```
@Entity
public class Advert extends DomainObject implements Comparable<Advert> {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Unowned
    private AdvertType advertType;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class AdvertType extends DomainObject implements Comparable<AdvertType> {
    private Integer position;
    private String typeId;
    private String titleMain;
}

@Entity
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class DomainObject implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
}
```

Log:

```
2013-04-20 12:48:17 DEBUG Query:58 - QueryCompilation:
  [from:ClassExpression(alias=x)]
  [filter:DyadicExpression{DyadicExpression{PrimaryExpression{x.advertType}  =  Literal{15}}  OR  DyadicExpression{PrimaryExpression{x.advertType}  =  Literal{20}}}]
  [symbols: x type=net.org.selector.animals.domain.Advert]
2013-04-20 12:48:17 DEBUG Query:58 - JPQL Query : Executing "SELECT x FROM Advert x WHERE x.advertType in (15,20)" ...
2013-04-20 12:48:17 DEBUG Query:58 - Query compiled as : Kind=net.org.selector.animals.domain.Advert Filter : advertType_key=AdvertType(15) AND advertType_key=AdvertType(20) [QUERY-TYPE=NORMAL]
2013-04-20 12:48:17 DEBUG Native:58 - Executing query in datastore for SELECT x FROM Advert x WHERE x.advertType in (15,20)
```

So why query compiled as:

advertType_key=AdvertType(15) **AND** advertType_key=AdvertType(20)

instead of

advertType_key=AdvertType(15) **OR** advertType_key=AdvertType(20)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is flawed. "x.advertType" is of type AdvertType so it cannot be "in" a List of numerics. "x.advertType.typeId" could possibly be used if it was in a List of Strings. Also the log tells you what low-level query is actually invoked

Comment: Hi thx for reply.
I added the most interesting part of the log and corrected the question.

Comment: I refer to valid JPQL that is portable. it is possible to write portable JPQL, not something that Google particularly care about